# Custom simple_form wrapper to match Bootstrap 4 checkboxes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, forms, simple-form

I'm trying to create a simple_form wrapper to match Bootstrap 4's stacked checkboxes/radios.

Here's the HTML structure I'd like to replicate, courtesy of [Boostrap's docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#default-stacked):

```
<div class="form-check">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check disabled">
  <label class="form-check-label">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" disabled>
    Option two is disabled
  </label>
</div>
```

Here's where my simple_form wrapper stands currently:

```
config.wrappers :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.optional :readonly
  b.use :label
  b.use :input, class: "form-check-input"
  b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback' }
  b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'small', class: 'form-text text-muted' }
end
```

And here's the HTML structure it outputs currently:

```
<span class="checkbox">
  <label for="">
    <input class="form-check-input check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="">
    Text for checkbox goes here
  </label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE 05/2018**

SimpleForm released a new version that [ships a Bootstrap 4.1 generator](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/1569). Make sure to have Version 4.0.0+ installed:

```
gem 'simple_form', '~> 4.0.0'
```

and then you can generate the new initializer file with:

```
rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

Make sure to use Bootstrap 4.1 though, there are some subtle differences.

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

After digging through the [source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/tags.rb#L20), i've found the relevant options `item_wrapper_class` and `item_wrapper_label` that need to be passed to the wrapper config:

```rb
 config.wrappers(:vertical_radio_and_checkboxes, tag: 'div', 
    class: 'form-group', 
    error_class: 'has-error',
    item_wrapper_class: 'form-check', 
    item_label_class: 'form-check-label') do |b|
   b.use :html5
   b.optional :readonly
   b.use :label, class: 'form-control-label'
   b.use :input, class: 'form-check-input'
   b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback' }
   b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'small', class: 'form-text text-muted' }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what changed exactly, but for me the following seems to work when generating simple_form with bootstrap 3 generators, editing them to mimic the bootstrap 4 wrappers and applying @stwienert his answer:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Append bootstrap 4 is-invalid class
inputs = %w[
  BooleanInput
  CollectionCheckBoxesInput
  CollectionInput
  CollectionRadioButtonsInput
  CollectionSelectInput
  DateTimeInput
  FileInput
  GroupedCollectionSelectInput
  NumericInput
  PasswordInput
  RangeInput
  StringInput
  TextInput
]

inputs.each do |input_type|
  superclass = "SimpleForm::Inputs::#{input_type}".constantize

  new_class = Class.new(superclass) do
    def input_html_classes
      has_errors? ? super.push('is-invalid') : super
    end
  end

  Object.const_set(input_type, new_class)
end

# Use this setup block to configure all options available in SimpleForm.
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.error_notification_class = 'alert alert-danger'
  config.button_class = 'btn btn-primary'
  config.boolean_label_class = nil

  config.wrappers :vertical_form, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group',
                                  error_class: 'is-invalid' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :minlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label

    b.use :input, class: 'form-control'
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback' }
  end

  config.wrappers :vertical_file_input, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group',
                                        error_class: 'is-invalid' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :minlength
    b.optional :readonly
    b.use :label, class: 'control-label'

    b.use :input
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback' }
  end

  config.wrappers(:vertical_boolean, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', item_wrapper_class: 'form-check', item_label_class: 'form-check-label') do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly

    b.wrapper 'div', class: 'form-check' do |ba|
      ba.use :input, class: 'form-check-input'
      ba.use :label, class: 'form-check-label'
      ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback' }
    end
  end
end
```

Don't forget to set:

```
config.boolean_style = :inline
```

in the simple_form.rb config

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my `:vertical_boolean` in `config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb` wrapper to look like this:

```
config.boolean_style = :inline
config.wrappers :vertical_boolean, tag: 'div', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'has-error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.optional :readonly

  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'form-check' do |ba|
    ba.use :input, class: 'form-check-input'
    ba.use :label, class: 'form-check-label'
  end

  b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-block' }
  b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
end
```

That appeared to do the trick nicely for me.